# passing JSON string from iOS WKWebKit to JS , always failure

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, reactjs, wkwebview

I'm trying to call an function in JS with a string parameter from iOS application (swift). and I expect the data structure like :

```
[{"name":"Mat. Category","value":"PIPE"},
{"name":"Manufacturer","value":"Manufacturer 1"},
{"name":"Heat#","value":"78652457"},
{"name":"Manufacture Date","value":"2019-04-15"},
{"name":"Item Description","value":"8\" PIPE, 18\" LG"},
{"name":"Wall Thickness","value":"0.375IN"},
{"name":"Diameter","value":"24IN UPS"},
{"name":"Yield Strength","value":"35,000 psi"},
{"name":"Document Repository Link","value":"https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SPB7-R1p_UWEWnG9H6rx0SX3LTpDSG_L"}
];
```

so , it's an array with some objects. and I'm passing it from iOS :

```swift
   webPage.evaluateJavaScript("cameraClosed(\(content))") { (res, error) in
            if error == nil{

                print("invoke successed")
                print("res:\(res)")
            }else{
                print("invoke failure")
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

the content is a string. I print the javascriptstring that passing to web :

print "cameraClosed((content))" =>

```swift
cameraClosed([{"name":"Mat. Category","value":"Aaron"},{"name":"Manufacturer","value":"Manufacturer 1"},{"name":"Heat#","value":"18616949864"},{"name":"Manufacture Date","value":"2019-04-14"},{"name":"Item Description","value":"8\" Steel Gas main - 50 Ft"},{"name":"Wall Thickness","value":"0.375IN"},{"name":"Diameter","value":"24IN UPS"},{"name":"Yield Strength","value":"35,000 psi"},{"name":"Document Repository Link","value":"https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SPB7-R1p_UWEWnG9H6rx0SX3LTpDSG_L"}])
```

and in the web side , I can receive this successfully, here is my React code:

```
 window.cameraClosed = (content) => {

      if (typeof (content) == "string") {
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.messageRecieved.postMessage("is String");
      }else{
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.messageRecieved.postMessage("is Object");
      }
}
```

and I print the `content` that received in React(using messageHandlers ) because the `content` is comes from a QRcode, so I can't debug it in PC , I can only use the iOS device and a embed WKWebView :

```
(
        {
        name = "Mat. Category";
        value = Aaron;
    },
        {
        name = Manufacturer;
        value = "Manufacturer 1";
    },

        {
        name = "Heat#";
        value = 18616949864;
    },
        {
        name = "Manufacture Date";
        value = "2019-04-14";
    },
        {
        name = "Item Description";
        value = "8\" Steel Gas main - 50 Ft";
    },
        {
        name = "Wall Thickness";
        value = "0.375IN";
    },
        {
        name = Diameter;
        value = "24IN UPS";
    },
        {
        name = "Yield Strength";
        value = "35,000 psi";
    },
        {
        name = "Document Repository Link";
        value = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SPB7-R1p_UWEWnG9H6rx0SX3LTpDSG_L";
    }
)
```

I don't know why it turns the square brackets into parentheses.and it really confused me. I just want a right data structure as I mentioned before. it comes from a QRCode, and I think I make the right data structure in QRCode,but I don't know why it changed after I passing it to web.

can anyone help me ?

Comment: I don't really understand what your problem is programming wise? Is this a swift question or a reactjs question or something else? As far as swift goes, just because it prints with parentheses doesn't mean the brackets has been replaced in the actual string

Comment: it has been replaced , because the variable that I'm printed are all strings .. but I have fix it . I will write my solution later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by doing stringify one more time :

```
 let string = JSON.stringify(content)
 let jsonArry = JSON.parse(string)
```

then the square brackets comes back.